# Unmount a volume as soon as its inserted if its name is "XYZ"

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

I have a USB modem which is mounted as say XYZ(which contains the Dialer Software and Readme)  when its inserted. In order to connect using it, I have to eject it and then connect it using ppp dialer.

Let us say that it mounts under the name /Volumes/XYZ

I want to do something like if I insert a USB device and it mounts under the name XYZ, I want it to be ejected immediately.

How do I do that?

Comment: Did one of these solutions work, and if not, what's the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did something similar once upon a time, where whenever a drive named a certain way was mounted, a script immediately fired off to sync the contents of a set of folders to the drive.

To do something similar here, the script would need to look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -d /Volumes/XYZ ];
    then
    echo “Ejecting XYZ!”;
    umount /Volumes/XYZ
    exit;
fi
```

Save it somewhere, your `~/bin/` directory if you have one, or maybe `~/Library/Scripts/`, just remember where.

The second piece of the puzzle is the LaunchAgent that will actually handle the event whenever a drive is mounted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.superuser.226504.example</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Path/To/Script/unmount-modem.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>QueueDirectories</key>
    <array/>
    <key>StartOnMount</key>
    <true/>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

That needs to be saved as a .plist (named similar to the string used in place of “com.superuser.226504.example”) and saved to `~/Library/LaunchAgents`.  You can either load it from the terminal via `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/pathtoplist` or log out / log back in and it should get loaded if everything is configured properly.

Comment: Maybe [MarcoPolo](http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/) can be used to detect the drive instead? (Not sure if that makes things easier though. Nice answer!)

Comment: I haven’t used MarcoPolo before, but looking over the website, it could probably handle it too, in place of a LaunchAgent.  I’m a fan of launchd and making things work with the native implementations though :)

Comment: I love `StartOnMount`. Great answer!

Comment: @peelman I followed what you said but the drive is still mounting.. Please help. http://pastebin.com/rUUJgS2F

Comment: @shady There's a difference between "mounting and immediately unmounting" and "preventing mounting". Peelman's answer (as well as mine) only can do the former, just as you wanted in your question.

Comment: @Daniel I meant that the drive remains mounted even after doing all this. Its as if the shell is not getting executed.

Comment: @shady Change the volume name in the shell script to the one of your modem. Save the XML file with a `plist` extension, e.g. `com.superuser.226504.example.plist`. Specify the actual path to the script on your system in the XML file. Don't specify the path to the shell script using relative paths, only absolute and without ~ for your home directory. Make the shell script executable using `chmod +x unmount-modem.sh`.

Comment: @Daniel Thats what I did. Please see this link which I also posted earlier.. http://pastebin.com/rUUJgS2F

Comment: @shady You have a trailing `/` in the if condition, don't know if that makes a difference though. What happens when you `$ /bin/unmount-modem.sh`? You can also open `/Applications/Utilities/Console.app` and look for error messages by launchd. And, lastly, you can try using my answer :-)

Comment: @shady there are huge rings of permissions surrounding launchd items, for obvious reasons; they are version powerful tools that can be used for good and bad purposes. You most likely can’t run a root-owned script from a protected portion of the drive, from a user-owned launchd item inside your home directory.  move the script or move the launchd item.

Comment: Also, this script will ONLY run when a new drive is mounted, and it will ONLY unmount that newly mounted drive (pending the names match).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following AppleScript:

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
    set the item_count to the number of items in the added_items

    if the item_count is greater than 1 then
        display dialog "Multiple additions, I can't handle that!"
    else
        set the volume_name_raw to (item 1 of the items in the added_items as text)
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ":"
        set volume_name to text item 1 of volume_name_raw as text
        if volume_name is "Carbon Copy Cloner" then
            do shell script "hdiutil detach '/Volumes/" & volume_name & "'"
        end if
    end if
end adding folder items to
```

<sup>Based on the folder action "new item alert" by Apple</sup>

Change the name of the volume you want to eject in the following line:

```
if volume_name is "Carbon Copy Cloner" then
```

---

To activate it:

1. Open `/Applications/Utilities/AppleScript Editor` and paste the script above.
2. Save it as a script (e.g. `eject.scpt`) in `~/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts/`.
3. Close AppleScript Editor.
4. Right-click any folder in Finder, select *Services » Folder Actions Setup*
5. Dismiss the sheet dialog.
6. Check *Enable Folder Actions*
7. Click the `+` button to the lower left, and press `Command-Shift-G` in the resulting file dialog. Enter `/Volumes`. **Don't select an item, just press OK**.
8. Select the list entry `Volumes` and click the `+` button below the right side list.
9. Select `eject.scpt` in the sheet dialog and click *Attach*
10. Close *Folder Actions Setup*.

Done!