# how can I monitor a folder for changes or activities?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

I want to delete my macport folder but I'm not sure if there is something important in it. So my idea was to observe the folder a time. Is this possible?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by *observing*. Changes to the files in there, additions and removals?

Comment: I mean if there is a program which is using any file from this folder.

Comment: This will be difficult.  While you can use `fs_usage`, it's not in any way set up to run persistently (it even required root privileges). Looking forward to answers by others though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Folder Actions](http://www.apple.com/pro/tips/folderactions.html).

Alternatively, you can try starting a script using [launchd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd) with a `WatchPaths`. I'm pretty sure [this](https://superuser.com/questions/226504/unmount-a-volume-as-soon-as-its-inserted-if-its-name-is-xyz/226523#226523) answer can easily be adapted, by removing `StartOnMount` and specifying `WatchPaths`.

You can notify e.g. using the program `say` (audio notifications), or, if you use it, Growl from command line using `growlnotify`. If you want the latter to be really fancy, [this](https://superuser.com/questions/225069/specify-display-style-to-use-with-the-growlnotify-command-line-utility/225097#225097) answer might help with that.