# How to monitor a folder for changes, and execute a command if it does, on Windows?

Tags: windows, filesystems, monitoring

There are similar questions for [Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes) and [Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/229566/how-can-i-monitor-a-folder-for-changes-or-activities), but I'm after a Windows solution here.

The problem is as follows: I want to write several (js) script files in a folder, and have a  program monitor that folder for file changes and new files being added, and run a command whenever that happens (to compile them all into one single file).

The solution has to:

1. Monitor both file changes and new files being added, in a folder.
2. Run a command *only* if there is any change.

It would be best if it either is a built-in solution (like a JScript or VBscript snippet), or something that does not require installation.

Comment: see [this blog](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/3-portable-tools-monitor-files-folders-changes/) for some apps for windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a program called Belvedere that might do the trick.

http://ca.lifehacker.com/341950/belvedere-automates-your-self+cleaning-pc

It's a stand alone Windows app that runs in the background.

I've set it up to monitor my downloads folder for files with certain extensions with last modified dates of a day old.  The files it finds, it deletes, however you could have it run an action instead.

Comment: Wow - that one looks super nice. I'll choose this as an answer (even if I already got what I needed from another one) since it probably is much more useful and versatile than the one I'm using, for other people (and maybe me in the future!). +1 and accepted!

Comment: Belvedere made me lose hours to eventually figure out it's [full of unsolved bugs](https://github.com/mshorts/belvedere/issues), especially with custom commands. Try [FolderMonitor](http://www.nodesoft.com/foldermonitor) instead (and use `"{0}{1}"` in the parameter field, including the quotes). Only issue: you can't define a separate command for each folder. Just one, globally.

Comment: @bfred.it Belvedere does have its issues, but it worked for me.  FolderMonitor looks like a good solution too.  I think it's the one the user asking the question [ended up with](http://superuser.com/a/468671/143655).

Answer (score 14):

I've had good success with an old program called Log Monitor.  It's ancient, and long ago abandoned.  But it serves the purpose pretty well.

http://www.freeware-guide.com/download/index2.html

Comment: Ah, thanks. I'm currently trying out [another utility](http://www.nodesoft.com/foldermonitor), but +1!

Comment: this awsome "thing" is working perfectly on windows 10 !

Answer (score 9):

I have created a simple utility for this purpose:
https://github.com/benblamey/when_changed

usage: when_changed (file path) (command) (optional-parameters)

e.g. when_changed C:\somedir\foo.txt myapp.exe bar wibble 123

Comment: I like how that's an elegant API. Does it support folders recursively?

Comment: Yes:  when_changed C:\\**.txt foo.exe

I wanted a no-dep version of https://github.com/joh/when-changed for windows.

Answer (score 7):

With .NET watchfolders this is really easy to code. I'm sure someone have done such a program.

Just found this gem for you
http://www.guidingtech.com/9861/automate-folder-actions-windows-watch-4-folder/

Comment: I'm aware of how easy it is to code this in .NET - I just didn't want to. But I'm trying [this one](http://www.nodesoft.com/foldermonitor) which is free, may just work too! +1 for the recommendation, that one seems nice too.

Answer (score 5):

I'm currently trying [this app](http://www.nodesoft.com/foldermonitor), which requires .NET, but looks like it does the job.

Answer (score 4):

Yet another tool: https://github.com/yankee42/java-file-change-watcher

Advantages: Platform independent (Java), small (10KB).

Disclaimer: I am the author

Comment: I liked the idea of this, but it seems to use a lot of CPU. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do a built-in solution using JScript or VBScript, then what you want to look for is file system monitoring using WMI event subscriptions. Basically you write the code to monitor a folder and preform actions when a change is detected such as:

- `__InstanceCreationEvent`
- `__InstanceDeletionEvent`
- `__InstanceModificationEvent`

...and your script runs on an interval watching for these events to occur. There are many resources, but here are some for VBScript and Powershell:

- [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42212/WMI-and-File-System-Monitoring)
- [Blog post](http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/?p=1951)
- [Thread in microsoft.public.windows.server.scripting](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.windows.server.scripting/browse_thread/thread/2110a4d66d6333a4?pli=1)

Answer (score 2):

This is such a common requirement that I'm surprised there's no convenient utility built into the OS itself.

Anyway as mentioned earlier I've used [LogMonitor](http://www.freeware-guide.com/download/index2.html) successfully in the past. However I found [this blog post](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/3-portable-tools-monitor-files-folders-changes/) informative and am using [Watch 4 Folder](http://leelusoft.blogspot.com/) now.

Hopefully this helps you out.

Comment: +1, but I wouldn't say it's a "common requirement" for anyone except us developers... And for that matter, there are system calls to monitor the filesystem, so that counts as "OS integration" I guess.

Comment: Well I was seeing it from businesses & network share's perspective. You always want to know who to blame when a files goes missing :P. I am in the middle of diagnosing such a situation right now :/

Answer (score 1):

NirSoft has software for monitor files changes on Windows
FolderChangesView

> FolderChangesView is a simple tool that monitors the folder or disk drive that you choose and lists every filename that is being modified, created, or deleted while the folder is being monitored.
>   You can use FolderChangesView with any local disk drive or with a remote network share, as long as you have read permission to the selected folder.

[image]

you can download it for free from [here](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/folderchangesview.zip)
[More Info](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/folder_changes_view.html)

Comment: Seems more of an informational/debugging tool than an automation one, but still interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/ which subscribes to os-specific filesystem monitoring events. The code is years old but still works (at least on the Windows Server 2013r2 I was testing it yesterday).

There is also github resurrection of jnotify project on https://github.com/redbooth/jnotify which does not offer standalone demo app but (according to commit logs) patches some bugs.

In java7 there should be some kind of inotify-like filesystem watch too, but I was not testing it yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with polling for changes then https://github.com/radovskyb/watcher is another option. It's a Go package but it also provides a command line interface.

1. Install Go (e.g. `choco install golang` or follow https://golang.org/dl/).
2. Ensure `go` is in your PATH by running `go version`. The installation from step 1 should add `%UserProfile%/go/bin` to PATH.
3. Run `go get -u github.com/radovskyb/watcher/...` as instructed in the [readme](https://github.com/radovskyb/watcher#installation).
4. Run `watcher -cmd="your_command"` inside the desired directory (e.g. `watcher -cmd="npm run build" javascript/*`).

This should also work on non-Windows platforms, it's simple polling after all.

This shouldn't require Go to run because all binaries from `%UserProfile%/go/bin` are statically linked. So you can then move the couple of executables somewhere else and remove Go.