# Can /etc/hosts or something similar be used to redirect a http URL to a file path?

Tags: windows-7, proxy, hosts-file

My Windows 7 admin pushes out some proxy settings (e.g., a proxy.pac file available through http) to my computer every night that I don't want. I have modified this pac-file and stored it locally, on C:. Currently I have to replace the http URL to a file path every morning. Would it be possibe, maybe using the host-file, to redirect this http URL to a file path? Convincing my admin to stop changing my network settings is not gonna happen, hence I am looking for a workaround.

I am local admin on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

> ould it be possibe, maybe using the host-file, to redirect this http URL
>   to a file path?

No. The hosts file translates host-names into IP addresses. It does not do 
anything with file paths. (In fact it does very little, being designedin an era where computing resources were very limited).

> Hence I am looking for a workaround.

Maybe we can help with that though. How does the new pac get pushed? What happens if you make the file you modified read-only?  Or (ugly but likely working) how about replacing the pac with a copy from your userfolder by placing a batch-file in the startup folder?

Comment: I don't know how it gets pushed. Probably with some group policy or similar. It is changed every morning when I login. My modified file is on C:, it is not affected by whatever method is used to change my LAN proxy settings so no real point in making it read only. How would a batch file in my startup folder help? Or do you assume I shut down my computer every day? Is there a "startup folder" that is run every time I login? That could be a solution.

Comment: Yes. I did assume that the computer got shut down daily. That seems to be the default at most firms were I worked. If it does not than. Maybe something with a file monitoring program? Keep looking at the pac file. If it changes execute the command to overwrite it? Feels like a kludge though.

http://superuser.com/questions/468662/how-to-monitor-a-folder-for-changes-and-execute-a-command-if-it-does-on-window

Comment: The pac file is not change, they change the path to the pac script in the LAN-settings.